# How to create a new column based on binary values of others columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset like the df below:

```
Person   atrib1  atrib2  atrib3   atrib4
Paulo      0      1       0         1
Andres     1      1       0         1
```

I want a to create a new column `atrib_list` with a list of the atrib where the value it's value is 1 like this output:

```
Person   atrib1  atrib2  atrib3   atrib4     atrib_list
Paulo      0      1       0         1        ['atrib2',atrib4']
Andres     1      1       0         1        ['atrib1','atrib2','atrib4]
```

I am trying something like this:

```
df['atrib_list'] = df.apply(lambda x: x for x in df.columns if df.value==1)
```

but it's completly wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your output

```
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda y: [z  for x,z in zip(y,y.index) if x==1] ,axis=1)
Out[308]: 
0            [atrib2, atrib4]
1    [atrib1, atrib2, atrib4]
dtype: object
```

Comment: why when I try to filter the final df this way:  `filter_df = df[len(df['new']>1)]  it gives me an error: `'>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'` ?

Comment: if I do `len(df['new'][0]` it gives 2 and it's correct.  But if i use the same logic to filter df when len 'new' > 1 it gives the above error

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df['atrib_list'] = (df
   .filter(like='atrib').replace(0, pd.NA)
   .stack().reset_index(1)
   .groupby(level=0)['level_1'].agg(list)
)
```

Other idea using [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress):

```
from itertools import compress

cols = list(df.filter(like='atrib'))
df['atrib_list'] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: list(compress(cols, x)), axis=1)
```

output:

```
   Person  atrib1  atrib2  atrib3  atrib4                atrib_list
0   Paulo       0       1       0       1          [atrib2, atrib4]
1  Andres       1       1       0       1  [atrib1, atrib2, atrib4]
```